# C++ - Can I pass child class as parameter instead of base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have this:

```
class DATABASE_API MySQLConnection
{
}
```

And then a child class:

```
class DATABASE_API WorldDatabaseConnection : public MySQLConnection
{
}
```

Then I have this:

```
class GameDatabase {
public:
    GameDatabase(PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection>* preparedStatement, GameDatabaseFlags gdf)
    {
        _gameObjectDatabaseFlag = gdf;
        _preparedStatement = preparedStatement;
    };
    GameDatabaseFlags _gameObjectDatabaseFlag;
protected:
    uint32_t versionId;
    virtual void MapGameDatabase(GameDatabaseContainer gameDatabaseContainer) = 0;
    PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection>* _preparedStatement;
};
```

When I try to initialize `GameDatabase` like so:

```
PreparedStatement<WorldDatabaseConnection> * stmt = WorldDatabase.GetPreparedStatement(WORLD_SEL_GAMEOBJECTS_TEMPLATE);

auto gameDatabase = new GameDatabase(stmt,GAMEOBJECTS_DB);
```

I get the following error:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'GameDatabase'

Why is that? Can't I simple use the child class `WorldDatabaseConnection` in place of the base class `MySQLConnection`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I just spent a few minutes trying to reproduce the same error and had to edit some of your code and add a lot to it. Also, the kernel of your question seems to have to do with inheritance and constructors, so there's no need to for such a convoluted example with such long names.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `WorldDatabaseConnection` is a child class of `MySQLConnection`, the template class `PreparedStatement<WorldDatabaseConnection>` is not a child class of `PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection>`.

Comment: I really don't understand how that solves the issue ? Maybe I need reinterpret_cast ?

Comment: It does not solve the issue (sorry), but it is the explanation why you cannot do what you are trying.

Comment: @Venelin - its a very very long 'No'

Comment: @Venelin You can pass a (pointer to a) child class object as parameter instead of a base class object (as you ask in the headline), but that is not what you are doing because an object of type `PreparedStatement<WorldDatabaseConnection>` is not an object of a child class of `PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection>`. Hence the answer.

Comment: @nielsen so If I understand you correctly it should be `GameDatabase(PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection*>* preparedStatement, GameDatabaseFlags gdf)` ?

Comment: @Venelin That may help, but most importantly, `WorldDatabaseConnection::GetPreparedStatement()` must be changed to return a pointer to an object of type  `PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection *>` or `PreparedStatement<MySQLConnection>`.